# How much power can be drawn from Apple Lightning port for a device?

Tags: iphone, power, lightning

I need some help and would love to find a developer to help me figure out how much power can be drawn from the Lightning port for a powered device ... similar to a fan or a camera connected to the Lightning port and how to do it.